# Unusual Rails Mongoid case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

Previously we had has_one and belongs_to relation with our models:

```
class Task
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    has_one :output
end

class Output
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    belongs_to :task
end
```

But we now plan to embed output inside task.

```
class Task
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    embeds_one :output
end

class Output
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    embedded_in :task
end
```

Everything works fine but we want to make backward compatible. ie. we want those output also which were created before embed.

Then, we did this method in task.rb:

```
def output
    Task.collection.find(_id: Moped::BSON::ObjectId(self.id)).first.output ||    Output.collection.find(task_id: Moped::BSON::ObjectId(self.id)).first
end
```

The problem with this is now task.output will give json instead of output object.
so we cannot do

```
task = Task.new
output = task.create_output
output.task #=> not possible
```

Anyone having this scenario or any directions for this case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, instead of making a workaround, why dont we migrate the old ones?

First, change both models to embed by replacing has_one with embeds_one and replacing belongs_to with embedded_in. Save the code.

Then use your rails console (>> rails console)

Then

```
Output.each do |o|
   if !o.task_id.nil?
      #change to embedded format
      t=Task.find(o.task_id)
      t.output=o
      t.output.task_id=nil
      t.save
    end
end
```

Comment: Well I had thought of this, but I have over million records of Task and Output , so I was doubting this ...